# Error integrating PAX-EXAM with JBehave

Tags: jbehave, pax-exam

Get this error when I try to start a PAX-EXAM based test with Jbehave
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder not found by PAXEXAM-PROBE

Karaf version: 3.0.0
PAX-EXAM : 3.4.0
org.apache.felix.framework: 4.2.1
Junit : 4.11
jbehave-core : 3.9.5

@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
public class HMStoryRunner extends AbstractTest {

Comment: How did you "integrate" Pax Exam and JBehave?

Comment: I used  Annotation @RunWith(PaxExam.class)  and then any test methods in the HMStoryRunner class were annotated with: